# How can I use a python output as a matlab input?

Tags: python, matlab, input, output

I have a python code that works perfectly fine, and I want to use the output of the python's code as an input in the matlab one, How can I do that ?

Comment: I think you're looking for https://blogs.mathworks.com/student-lounge/2020/09/14/using-matlab-and-python-together/

Answer (score 0):

Linux shell has pipeline operator `|`, that allows to forward output from one command to the input of the second command. Imagine we have 2 python programs, a.py:

```py
print(1)
print(2)
```

and b.py:

```py
i = int(input())
j = int(input())

print(i + j)
```

So having these two commands, you need to run them like this:

```bash
~> python3 a.py | python3 b.py
3
```

Adapting this to your problem, second command will be matlab program, not python3